# Microsoft visual studio 2013 is busy error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

In the past few days, I started to get an error.
Every time I press F5 to debug my Windows phone 8 application on wp8 device, 
After five seconds it stuck and displays:

> Microsoft Visual Studio is busy

And that it restart the visual studio.

I already tried to repair it, 
repair update 3,
re-install resharper 
and nothing helped.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try below thing it works for me when I face this type of problem :-

```
Start -> RUN -> iisreset
```

the problem is that IIS doesn't restart each time you start up your pc.
Simpy run the command (either in the Command Prompt, or "Run" function) "iisreset"

VS instantly woke up after iisreset in my case. I hope it will help you too.

Some extra information :-

http://geekswithblogs.net/sevenfortytwo/archive/2006/11/23/97947.aspx

Comment: not really helpful (rather a comment than a down vote).... Visual Studio 2013 is always busy... Doesn`t even redraw exposed regions... Still looking for a solution, hope to remember to post here when (and if) I find any........